# Why does shading mode show world view? I want to take it off to normal view

Tags: modeling, shaders

My object is fine and I can render fine but in shading mode it opens up in world view mode. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Why did it stop.